# If $ab^2+1 = c^2+d^2$ with $a$ squarefree, what [else] can be said about $a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

What is known about squarefree integers $a$ where there exist non-zero integers $b$, $c$, and $d$, with $\gcd(b,c)=\gcd(b,d)=1$, such that 
$$ab^2+1=c^2+d^2$$
?

EDIT: As pointed out by individ, if an integer $g>1$ exists such that $g \mid \gcd(b,c)$, then $b=gb_1$ and $c=gc_1$ yields
\begin{align}
a(gb_1)^2 + 1 &= (gc_1)^2+d^2  \\
d^2 - (ab_1^2-c_1^2)g^2 = 1.
\end{align}
Now if $ab_1^2-c_1^2$ is not a square, there are infinite solutions. So to make the question less trivial, we may assume $\gcd(b,c)=\gcd(b,d)=1$.

Comment: Are you asking what's known about the set of integers $a$ for which $b$, $c$, and $d$ exist?  If so, I think there is a conjecture that says that, for any $A\gt0$, $An^2+1$ is prime for infinitely many $n$, so letting $A=4a$ and $b=2n$ gives primes congruent to $1$ mod $4$, all of which are expressible as the sum of two squares.

Comment: I believe an interesting subset to this question is for what $n$ does $$x^2+y^2-nz^2=1$$ have a solution with $xyz \neq0$. Is it (like Pell equations) for all non-square $n$?

Comment: @BarryCipra: Yes, that's a good way of asking what I want to know. Thanks — edited!

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: A quick brute-force search suggests that $a$ can only contain primes of the form $4n+1$.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan, I'm not sure what you mean.  My comment implies that, conjecturally, *all* $a$ are possible.  For example,  $3\cdot2^2+1=2^2+3^2$.

Comment: Kieren Macmillan Your conjecture that primes divisors of $ a$ are in the form $4n+1$ is wrong. Take $a=2,b=2,c=0,d=3$.$2.2^2+1=0^2+3^2$. @BarryCipra

Comment: @BarryCipra: Good point. Your non-trivial counterexample [the first one] is a good one. I'm editing the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the condition $\gcd(b,cd)=1$, one thing we can say for sure is that, if there is a solution to $ab^2+1=c^2+d^2$, then $a\equiv0$, $1$, $3$, $4$, or $7$ mod $8$.  This is because $b$ can never be even, since $2\mid b$ implies $c$ and $d$ are both odd, which makes $c^2+d^2\equiv2$ mod $4$ whereas $ab^2+1\equiv1$ mod $4$.  But if $b$ is odd, then $ab^2+1\equiv a+1$ mod $8$, whereas $c^2+d^2\equiv1$, $2$, $4$, $5$, or $0$ mod $8$.

Another way to say this is that there is definitely no solution if $a\equiv2$ mod $4$ or $5$ mod $8$.  If I had to guess, I'd say there probably *are* solutions for all $a$ in the other congruence classes.

Remark:  The condition $cd\not=0$ as well as $\gcd(b,cd)=1$ makes life a little more interesting than it would be if we allowed solutions of the form $(b,c,d)=(1,c,0)$.  For example, for $a=8$, $(b,c,d)=(1,3,0)$ would be an easy solution, but if it's disallowed, the next solution (i.e., the smallest value of $b$ that works) is $8\cdot17^2+1=48^2+3^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking for the equation. $$x^2+y^2=qz^2+1$$ For all values of the coefficient  $q$  There are solutions. It is easy to show.

Will make a replacement.  $y=as$ ; $z=bs$  Then.

$$x^2-(qb^2-a^2)s^2=1$$

This equation Pell. And we can always choose such numbers $a,b$ . To the expression  $(qb^2-a^2)$ It was not square.

Comment: Nicely done. I've added the restriction $\gcd(ab,c,d)=1$, to perhaps make it a more interesting question.

Comment: How do you do with $x^2+y^2=11z^2+1$ one of whose solutions is $(x,y,z)=(3,6,2)$? What do you say about $11$?

Comment: @Piquito, $(x,y,z)=(6,36,11)$.

Comment: @Piquito  $3^2-(11*1^2-3^2)*2^2=1$  Yes or no?

Comment: @individ, I think Piquito was alluding to the OP's new condition that $b$ (your $z$) be relatively prime to $c$ and $d$.

Comment: @individ: Dear friend, a true answer to the question is what has given Barry Cipra: conditions about $a$. By the way, this is a kind of error that I always I incur, I mean, not read thoroughly the question.Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might be worth setting up a community wiki to record solutions to $ab^2+1=c^2+d^2$ with $\gcd(b,cd)=1$ and $cd\not=0$, for positive values of $a$ congruent to $0$, $1$, $3$, $4$, and $7$ mod $8$ (which my other answer established as the only congruence classes for which solutions might exist), and with $b$ **as small as possible**.  I hope others will extend the list and/or correct any mistakes I (or others) may have made.  (It's easy enough to check if an entry is a correct solution, but it can be tricky to check that it uses the smallest possible $b$ -- e.g., why doesn't anything less than $b=17$ work for $a=8$?)

$$\begin{align}
1\cdot1^2+1 &=1^2+1^2\\
3\cdot7^2+1 &=12^2+2^2\\
4\cdot1^2+1 &=2^2+1^2\\
7\cdot1^2+1 &=2^2+2^2\\
8\cdot17^2+1 &=48^2+3^2\\
\\
9\cdot1^2+1 &=3^2+1^2\\
11\cdot11^2+1 &=36^2+6^2\\
12\cdot1^2+1 &=3^2+2^2\\
15\cdot13^2+1 &=50^2+6^2\\
16\cdot1^2+1 &=4^2+1^2\\
\\
17\cdot1^2+1 &=3^2+3^2\\
19\cdot1^2+1 &=4^2+2^2\\
20\cdot7^2+1 &=30^2+9^2\\
23\cdot23^2+1 &=78^2+78^2\\
24\cdot1^1+1 &=4^2+3^2\\
\\
25\cdot1^2+1 &=5^2+1^2\\
27\cdot19^2+1 &=98^2+12^2\\
28\cdot1^2+1 &=5^2+2^2\\
31\cdot1^2+1 &=4^2+4^2\\
32\cdot13^2+1 &=72^2+15^2\\
\\
33\cdot1^2+1 &=5^2+3^2
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is great! Thanks. I'll see if I can add examples.

Comment: Notice that $3,8,11,15,20,23$ are the first six [non-trivial] entries in https://oeis.org/A081858 (numbers $n$ such that $2n+1$ divides $2^n-1$). These and the two perfect powers $27=3^3$ and $32=2^5$ are the only entries in your list that require $b>1$. I wonder if that's provable, or simply a Strong Law of Small Numbers thing…

Comment: Strong Law… $39 \cdot 1^2 + 1 = 6^2+2^2$, and $39$ is in https://oeis.org/A081858.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan, it's also easy to see that $a=41$ requires $b\gt1$ since $42$ is not a sum of two squares, but $41$ is not in the OEIS sequence.